# "Commenter sur quelque chose" ou "commenter quelque chose"

Tags: prépositions

> Dessiner les huit schémas correspondant aux différentes choix
>   possibles pour le sens de chaque flèche (2 choix pour chacune des
>   trois flèches). **Commenter chacune des huit possibilités**, en
>   identifiant notamment celles qui sont interdites par le premier ou le
>   second principe de la thermodynamique.

Je me demande s'il faut dire "Commenter chacune des huit possibilités" ou "Commenter sur chacune des huit possibilités". Si tous deux sont possibles, quelle est la différence ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

J'écarterais ***commenter sur*** chacune des huit possibilités. Commenter s'utilise à peu près toujours transitivement, c'est à dire sans préposition :

> *Commenter chacune des huit possibilités*

[image]

On trouve quelques anciennes occurrences de *commenter sur* telle que :

> On commençoit donc dés lors à commenter sur les articles : on les tournoit, on les expliquoit à sa mode, on se cachoit de moy : Pourquoy : n'estoit qu'on sentoit dans sa conscience qu'on sortoit de nos premiers sentimens

Bossuet, *Relation sur le quiétisme*, 1698

Ici, *commenter sur* indique que le commentaire est négatif. ([Sens B 2 du TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/commenter), indiqué comme vieilli).

On trouve aussi des *commenter sur* modernes, où le commentaire ne concerne pas ce qui suit, mais *se trouve sur*.

> Il faudrait commenter sur le tableau prévu à cet effet.

Enfin, d'autres *commenter sur* sont probablement des anglicismes, sur le modèle de *comment on*, beaucoup se trouvant sur des traductions de l'anglais sur des sites canadiens.

cf. https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=%22commenter+sur%22

En revanche, on dit bien : *faire/écrire des **commentaires sur** quelque chose*.